# Why request body is always empty?

Tags: java, spring, post

I'm  trying to create simple spring CRUD, but post request for creation has always empty body.
If I fill object manually - everything works fine:

```
 @ResponseBody
 public Comment createOrUpdateComment(@RequestBody Comment comment) {

 comment.setIssueId(new Long(483162));
 comment.setUserId(new Long(2));
 comment.setComment("Comment");

 Comment updated = service.createOrUpdateComment(comment);
      return updated;
 }
```

Without manual setting - object is always empty, and fails to exception like `Column 'issue_id' cannot be null`
I'm sending request with the `Postman` like this:

[image: Request example]

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Please show your Comment class. I guess you should name your attributes like "userId" and "issueId".

Comment: check that annotation for method "createOrUpdateComment"

Comment: @Eduard you are exactly right! now everything works fine. Put you comment as an answer, than I can check it resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `property-naming-strategy` is `LOWER_CAMEL_CASE`.

Name your JSON attributes in lowerCamelCase like this:

```
{
    "userId": 1,
    "issueId": 483162,
    "comment": "comment"
}
```